# Automatic email aliases in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, office365

I know that with gmail accounts, you can add  `+` and additional text to an email address to make a pseudo-alias. That is, `sample+hello@gmail.com` will be delivered to `sample@gmail.com`, and the extra tag `+hello` could be used for sorting and filtering. I.e., it's easy to find all the messages sent to each alias, or have certain aliases skip the inbox and be ignored.

Is there an easy way to get similar functionality through a Microsoft account? My organization uses Office 365. I tried emailing `myemail+test@myorg.org`, but it got bounced back as undeliverable.

Answer (score 2):

The admin portal in the Office 365 User area has input boxes for creating aliases. There are several methods [outlined on Microsoft's TechNet blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hot/2012/04/26/how-to-add-an-alias-to-an-office-365-account-and-how-to-set-up-outlook-to-send-email-messages-as-this-alias/) as well as steps and pictures available [in a Microsoft Doc page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/email/add-another-email-alias-for-a-user?view=o365-worldwide) - ultimately boiling down to the version of 365 you have, how you guys have things configured, or any guidelines you may need to follow.

As far as sorting or additional functionality derived from the alias, you'd have to be more specific regarding what you'd be looking to do.